# Entity Framework: Select new attributes inside include

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Let's say, I have an Entity called Solutions which has multiple multimedia. I want to query Solutions and retrieve their list of multimedia, but I also want to Select only some fields and infer others from each of those multimedia such as follow:

```
IQueryable<Solution> result = db.Solutions
                .Include(s => s.Multimedia.Select(m => new MultimediaViewModel(){
                    ID = m.ID,
                    Name = m.Name,
                    Path = m.Path,
                    Preview = MultimediasController.ConvertVideo(m),
                    Extension = MultimediasController.GetExtension(m),
                    Type = m.Type
                }))
```

The following gives the System.ArgumentException exception with the message: "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties."

How is this achievable?

expected response would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Example",
        "subTitle": "Example 1",
        "multimedia": [
            {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "teste",
                "path": "/Upload_Public/Solution/27_.mp4",
                "preview": "/Upload_Public/Solution/27_preview.jpg",
                "extension": "mp4",
                "type": 0,
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use .Include for this. Just create an anonymous object and select off the properties you want.

```
IQueryable<Solution> result = db.Solutions
    .Select(s => new {
        s.Id,
        s.Title,
        s.Subtitle,
        Multimedia = new
        {
            s.Multimedia.ID,
            s.Multimedia.Name,
            s.Multimedia.Path,
            Preview = MultimediasController.ConvertVideo(m),
            Extension = MultimediasController.GetExtension(m),
            s.Multimedia.Type,
        }
    });
```

However, the method calls will likely result in a run-time error because the whole statement needs to be evaluated in the database. I'm not sure what those methods do, but you may have to bring back raw data and then extract the required info once the data is on the client.